# Android : menu cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android

This is how I do :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

game_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/new_game"
      android:title="@string/new_game"/>
<item android:id="@+id/help"
      android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

But Eclipse keep telling me that menu is not a type... I tried to import R, clean my project and some others things i saw on the net.

I cant bypass this problem with that :

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST + 1, 5, "??").setIcon(
                android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST + 2, 2, "??").setIcon(
                android.R.drawable.ic_menu_edit);
        return true; 
    }
```

Thank you in advance and sorry for my spelling.

Comment: add `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` before  `menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST + 1, 5, "??").setIcon( android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete);
`

Comment: argh sorry, my first code was a copy of my last, it's inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu); (see first post) which contain an error, not menu.add. I tried to add super... but same effect :(

Comment: The xml file must be in the `res/menu` folder. Also check that you have imported R class with a correct namespace and not android.R.

Comment: res/menu... damn me thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The xml file must be in the res/menu folder. Also check that you have
>   imported R class with a correct namespace and not android.R

Answer (score -1):

just add import android.view.MenuItem;